# type overrides type inside of class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i have a generic interface like this

```
type myType =  
{
 value1:string;
 value2:string;
  
}
```

and a class

```
 class array<myType> extends Array<myType>
{
   let a:myType;

   a.value1 ==> error.

}
```

the problem is that inside the class, the type myType is not read correct as it is another thing, how can i solve this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: that when i type `a.value1`, the autocompletion does not work, and says that there isn't that property while if i declare the same variable outside the class it works.

Comment: You need to initialize the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the elements of this array inferred to be `MyType`, declare a class with a unique name that extends `Array<MyType>`. Individual elements of the array can be referred to using `this[index]`.

Here's an example (and a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoDcCGANgK4QCMAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FroSQEyU0Mt2AX3YYAxgTxUqsBEgCCtWnhBQIAD2ARGAExmLlIADxxEkAHzoOzCMADCAewC2AIyYQdANS4QqACiYdDUpGIlcIWgBKK2xsAHo4qFBIKAcAMzUCCCdtYHlgAEldDSh6GSY0iNoPKClZMwgObDEHRhpM7Nz8oqD1KFRgAAsygG1AjQBddlioauAiWkYoAAMAEjQILJzGPMLi9QA6fGIyISh1zc6d7v2jn24hZY4hDBfxVvanOUgDFX6oRgQADu9QUShUfjQnBOFCgAHIABKbAgOOEAGmhPEocKBDloBB0cKgQkiogSUAACgJgDJEciHFBcfjCe82g4sgcUcw-F8Gr8QAcbPZnG5AV4fP4AAyRUlAA)):

```js
type MyType = {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
};

class MyTypeArray extends Array<MyType> {
  getCombinedValues(index: number) {
    // type of elementAtIndex is inferred as MyType
    const elementAtIndex = this[index];
    return `${elementAtIndex.value1} ${elementAtIndex.value2}`
  }
}

const myTypeArray = new MyTypeArray({ value1: 'Hello', value2: 'world' });

// Prints 'Hello world'
console.log(myTypeArray.getCombinedValues(0));
```